# Activities in button

Tags: java, swing, applet

where can i insert the class calling here in my code?

what i would like to happen is that when i click the button, the maze.java(the class that i would like to call) would run? ,thanks!

```
public class Main extends Applet {

    Button mazebutton;
    Button hexbutton;

    public void init() {

    mazebutton = new Button("Create a maxe");
    hexbutton = new Button ("Create a hexagonal Maze");

    mazebutton.setBounds(20,20,100,30);
    hexbutton.setBounds(20,70,100,40); 

    add(mazebutton);
    add(hexbutton);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to just makethe code like

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //here you need to call a function that you need to make
        //on "maze.java"  that returns the values of each variable
        //or starts by launching other function in the same class
        //(maze.java) that activates the game
    }
});
```